# How to implement app-like template?

Tags: html, css, templates, positioning

I am trying to build a website to make it look like an application template:

After reading a couple of tutorials here is what I've got so far:

[image]

It may look a bit complicated but I am explaining below:

My template contains a lot of div's some of them maybe extra, anyway by giving all the div's an absolute position and adding overflow-x and overflow-y whenever necessary I ended up with the template looking as above where the black bar indicates that I have the div scrolling as I want.

A couple of notes: 
Tasks table is a div which contains a big table inside that's why I added both vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Right panel div: has a lot of other div's and h3 tags with no specific styling just 4 to 5 div's with the same width of the right panel and different heights, that's why I wanted the right panel to scroll vertically.

Now my problem is that I have failed to make the right panel scroll horizontally, especially when I resize the browser widow. Actually it looks this way when I decrease the browser window width...

[image]

Even when I decrease the width more, it's like the right panel slides all the way covering both the center and the left panel. 
[image]

Is this supposed to happen? Why is the right panel not scrolling horizontally just like the center panel when the browser is resized? Is that because of the div's inside the right panel?

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way would be to calculate the width and height of task-controls and task-table via javascript or better jquery.

example for jquery

```
$(function() {
res();
$(window).resize(function() {
res();
});

function res(){
var windowWidth = $(window).width(); 
var leftPanelWidth = $('left-panel').width();  
var RightPanelWidth = $('left-panel').width();  
$('#task-controls','#task-table').width(windowWidth-leftPanelWidth-RightPanelWidth); 
}
});
```

edit:
here the complete, corrected and commented version

```
<!-- load jquery from the internet, if u dont want to download it -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
//run when dom (website) was load completly. same as "$(document).ready()"
$(function() {
    //call own function on first time
    res();

    //evertime when window will be reiszed by user
    $(window).resize(function() {
        //call function again
        res();
    });

    function res(){
        //get sizes
        var windowWidth = $(window).width(); 
        //the '#left-panel' searches for an html element with the id left-panel
        var leftPanelWidth = $('#left-panel').width();  
        var RightPanelWidth = $('#left-panel').width();  
        //set width for emements with ids #task-controls and #task-table. size is window width minus both menus
        $('#task-controls','#task-table').width(windowWidth-leftPanelWidth-RightPanelWidth); 
    }
});
</script>
```

if u want to build an app like website, you should learn jquery
http://api.jquery.com/
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

or did i missunderstood your question? you want to prevent the cropping of the center-panel

Comment: first thanks for your effort. let me correct myself, what I meant when I asked about your code is how it is supposed to help me fix my template because you can say I know more than 50% of jquery so I understood your code, I just don't think its gonna help, and I tried it actually , its not working :(,,

Comment: I will try to explain more about my problem, lets say I grabbed the right side of the browser window then I started to pull it to the left decreasing its width, what happens is that the right side is floating to the left till it covers both the center and the left panel, actually If I look closely I can see that the center and left panel are there just behind the right panel :S !